# Difference between these two count methods in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have been doing a count of "games" using spark-sql. The first way is like so:

```
val gamesByVersion = dataframe.groupBy("game_version", "server").count().withColumnRenamed("count", "patch_games")

val games_count1 = gamesByVersion.where($"game_version" === 1 && $"server" === 1)
```

The second is like this:

```
val gamesDf = dataframe.
  groupBy($"hero_id", $"position", $"game_version", $"server").count().
  withColumnRenamed("count", "hero_games")

val games_count2 = gamesDf.where($"game_version" === 1 && $"server" === 1).agg(sum("hero_games"))
```

For all intents and purposes `dataframe` just has the columns `hero_id`, `position`, `game_version` and `server`.

However `games_count1` ends up being about 10, and `games_count2` ends up being 50. Obviously these two counting methods are not equivalent or something else is going on, but I am trying to figure out: what is the reason for the difference between these?

Comment: Both queries should have given the same result. Can you post with sample data so that we can replicate the error and test it?

Answer (score 1):

I guess because in first query you group by only 2 columns and in the second 4 columns. Therefore, you may have less distinct groups just on two columns.